# reader.Read() is always empty...but why?

Tags: c#, database, if-statement

i have a problem. So i have the problem, that the if-query is not working. he will always jump in the else-path. But in the database is a entry, so it isnt empty...

```
      Jump:
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `depositRequests` LIMIT 1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            reader.Read();

            Log.Info("Durchlauf: " + i);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                SteamID SteamAddID = new SteamID(reader.GetString(2));
                string authCode = reader.GetString(3);

                Log.Info("SteamAddID: " + SteamAddID);
                Log.Info("AuthCode: " + authCode);
                Bot.log.Success("Add SteamAddID: " + SteamAddID + "AuthCode: " + authCode);

                AddFriendForTrade(SteamAddID, authCode);
            }
            else
            {
                Bot.log.Warn("No Data found! Waiting for Deposit Request");
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                reader.Close();
                i++;
                goto Jump;
            }
```

So why he always jump in the else-path although there is an entry in the database?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve with `Thread.Sleep(1000);`? [**`goto Jump` ???**](http://xkcd.com/292/) There are better alternatives: `while (true) { ...; if (condition) break; ... }` or `while (true) { ...; if (condition) return; ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are getting only *one* record, then reading it before `if` statement on this line:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
reader.Read(); <---
```

Since there is no second record,your second call to `Read` always returns *false*.

You should remove this line and call `Read` only once in your `if` statement or store the result of `Read` method and use that variable within the `if`:

```
bool isRecordExists = reader.Read();
if(isRecordExists)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you...i didnt see it!